# How can I modify the sub-set of an object in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
 let state = {
      
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March',
             'April', 'May'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Rainfall',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
        borderWidth: 2,
        data: [61, 62, 63, 64]
      }
    ]
  }
```

My problem is that I do not know how to modify the "data" field within the "datasets" field within the state object. I want to put my own variables instead of those fixed numbers(61,62,63,64 I mean). I am working on a React app that uses an API to retrieve the prices of different stocks in the market. But it seems that something simple stops me from completing my tasks. I can't wait to find out why I can't do that, have a nice day everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Let "response" be the data you are getting from your API(assuming you are making the api call from same component)
So as soon as you get the response you can set state like:

```
let arr = [..this.state.datasets]
arr[0].data= response ; // for multiple objects in array you can use loops
this.setState({
datasets: arr
})
```

Comment: I wanted to know that for example If I have the variables a, b, c, d, var a, b, c, d; and instead of data: [61, 62, 63, 64], if there is a way to create something like data: [a, b, c, d] directly